# Mac OS X 10.7 MySQL and MySQLdb

Tags: mysql, zsh, python-2.7, osx-lion

So I recently upgraded to 10.7 Lion as I am sure most people did.

I have been having some issues on trying to get MySQL to work again, and now all of the sudden my ./configure script doesn't work anymore.

everytime I run ./configure I get the following response.

```
zsh: no such file or directory: ./configure
```

Why could it be that ./configure has stopped working.

Here is a copy of my ~/.zshrc profile

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/8.4.8/bin/
#export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/8.4.8/bin/:$PATH"

#export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/8.4.8/bin
source /sw2/bin/init.sh
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

#export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME

source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: Is there a ./configure script where you run the command?

Comment: yes, there is, I have no idea why it seems to fail on that...

Comment: That's kind of unlikely. Does `less ./configure` work?

Answer (score 0):

So none of the suggested changes worked.
Everything just caused a lot of frustration.

I ended up rebuilding most of my libraries by getting rid of all installations of XCode and everything, rewrote my PATH so that `/usr/local/bin` was first to be seen and then re-compiled a lot of things, libjpeg, PIL, _imaging, MySQL, MySQLdb

Everything works fine now.